# If you've answered your own question with a bounty, why can you not receive a portion of the bounty back?

Tags: support, bounty

Can someone point me to an existing discussion on this? The scenario I had was:

- Posted a 50pt bounty for a question
- None of the answers resolved my issue
- I was able to get my issue corrected, and posted the answer in case anyone was curious
- My answer received 2 up-votes, and I marked it as the accepted answer
- My bounty expired today (my answer being the highest voted *and* the accepted answer)

So I was just wondering why, once the bounty expires, could a portion of the bounty not be given back to the original poster? In my specific situation, the answer I posted was the only answer with at least 2 up-votes (which is the requirement for 50% bounty auto-award). Could someone give me any insight on this?

Comment: Because that would essentially be a discount on the advertisement rate. Your post got the attention for which you paid; a self-answer doesn't refund that attention so you don't get back a (portion) of your bounty either.

Comment: I think the following situation is another reason why you can't refund the bounty to self answers. An OP offered a bounty. I assisted through a number of long and detailed debug steps, and suddenly the OP came up with an answer and accepted their own answer. I thought the OP was scamming to save bounty, but now I see he/she was just inconsiderate.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

A bounty should be seen as a give-away marketing campaign. Like the big prize people can win when they buy your product, a bounty can be won by whomever best answers your question.

However, to make it fair for everyone participating, you cannot award the price to yourself (*or any associates of your company or the marketing company that is promoting your product, or their family members, etc. etc.*); otherwise, what's the point of anyone else participating?

The bounty also pays for all the attention your question gets. Attention can bring along votes, hopefully feedback and answers. Self-answering does not undo all that attention that you bought, so you cannot get a (partial) refund on your bounty either.

Comment: That's not that much of a reference; that's just *from now on this won't be allowed anymore*; [Grace Note's answer on the same post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/55000/140890) looks more relevant.

Comment: Doesn't this just encourage people to create duplicate accounts? After all, if some "random" person X can post an answer and receive the points, why can't person Y who happens to be the OP? The attention was "paid" and so was the answer. But if the OP provides the answer, only the attention was paid, but not the answer. (also, award games exclude relatives because they might know the secret answer or they could rig the drawing in their favor)

Comment: @DavidBalažic: creating a duplicate account to receive the bounty won't get you anywhere, because that would be using an account to do something you could not normally do with just one account. If the moderators catch you at that behaviour they'll remove the extra account, and can get you a suspension too.

Comment: @DavidBalažic: And did you read the link I posted in my previous comment? You don't get to have a bounty refund, allowing you to award the post to your own answer would basically be a loophole that gives you a way out: get attention, self-answer, award the bounty back to yourself, and you got *free* attention for your question! That, in my book, is the same thing as knowing the answer to the sweepstakes up-front; you are cheating the system.

Comment: We have a situation here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37801921/1745001 where the OP posted a question, got the right answer from @JonathanLeffler at http://stackoverflow.com/a/37802421/1745001, then copied Jonathan's answer into their own answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/38018665/1745001 and accepted THAT as the right answer. When someone else (@BenjaminW) pointed out they'd done that the OPs response (flagged/removed now) to Benjamin was to "suck it". So, I'm very glad to hear that OP is still going to lose their Bounty points even if it doesn't go to the person who deserves it, Jonathan.