# Handle my own question with a bounty

Tags: discussion, questions, bounty

I've asked a question and offered a bounty for it. The question hasn't been answered. Now I managed to find a solution myself, but don't want post and answer, because the answer will likely turn into a small tutorial, and I'm not sure that it will be much helpful, as the question hasn't received much attention in the first place.

Now that I want to delete the question, the active bounty won't allow me to.

Other than waiting for the bounty to expire and deleting the question afterwards, how else can I handle the question?

I've seen a [similar question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251227/if-youve-answered-your-own-question-with-a-bounty-why-can-you-not-recieve-a-po), but unfortunately it doesn't apply to me.

Answer (score 2):

If you really, truly want to delete your question, custom flag your question for a moderator and explain your situation.  Be specific in what you want them to do and why you can't fix it yourself.  Your custom flag might read like this:

> I realized after adding the bounty that I really want to delete this question, but the bounty prevents me from deleting it myself.  I'd rather it be deleted now before anyone tries to answer the question.  Please delete the question for me.

Comment: ... As a side-note, the bounty won't be refunded either way, because you got the attention you paid for.